# Crontab: run a job once on Sunday and twice on the other week days

Tags: unix, cron, crontab

There is a way to run cron jobs on different days of the week, for example

```
0 8,16 * * 1-6
```

runs a job at 8:00 and 16:00 Monday to Saturday.

What if the job should run on Sunday as well, but only once (say, at 16:00 only)? Of course one can use 2 lines, one for Sunday only and one for Monday to Saturday. But is there a way to say that in a single crontab line?

Comment: If You want to solve it by crontab only, there's no way but write 2 or how many You need lines, each for one task. Another solution is run shell script which will run task twice or even run it every day but do Your custom time checks inside and run tasks as needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must add another line in cron like:

```
0 16 * * 7 /path/to/command
```

There is no way to do it in one line!

Comment: According to https://tecadmin.net/crontab-in-linux-with-20-examples-of-cron-schedule/ you can.

Comment: @SILENT, please demonstrate how. Answer on the question or add comment.

Comment: 0 8,16 * * 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 /script

Comment: @SILENT, this will run the script at 8h and 16h every day. OP want to have it run in Sunday only at 16h. Moreover its much mode sample to write your idea as `0 8,16 * * * /script`